# Здравствуйте! Как сделать при нажатии кнопки окрыватие дочернего окна?

Tags: c++, winapi

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки открывалось дочернее окно? Как можно зарегистрировать класс у дочернего окна?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
   public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
...
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
short result = GetAsyncKeyState('A');
if (result < 0 && (result & 0x01) == 0x01) {
  form2.Show();
}
```

Обьяснение: Первые две строчки мы инициализируем функцию GetAsyncKeyState. 
Далее мы обьявляем переменную класса второй формы (`Form2`) и проверяем, если нажата клавиша А - то показать форму.

Comment: Я новичок в это программирование на C++: WinAPI. Не могу понять куда писать. form2 form2 = new Form2();
short result = GetAsyncKeyState('A');
if (result < 0 && (result & 0x01) == 0x01) {
  form2.Show();
}, а также это куда писать [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
   public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

Comment: @Дмитрий это нужно писать по нажатию на кнопку. А первые две строчки писать после обьявления класса формы.